# Creating a custom view style in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view, view-styles

We're currently building a sharepoint 2013 site but the need to create a custom view style has now become apparent. When viewing documents, the following features would be ideal:

- The ability to specify conditional colour values based off dropdown
  values.
- The ability to add additional styles to a list view - table padding
  etc.
- The ability to show additional content to a list view - table headings
  etc.

As a short term solution we've enabled a thumbnail image to be chosen when a document is added, but this is less than ideal - especially for the client.

We can't seem to find any documentation on how to create a custom view style anywhere so your knowledge would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

P.S I should note that:

- We only have access to Sharepoint Designer 2013 and not 2010.
- We cannot use any external JS libaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript for that, a new property called "JSLink" is introduced in SharePoint 2013 list view webpart properties. Write a JavaScript inserting html on a conditional basis can solve your problem.

Comment: Does this reference external JS files to function properly? Or can this be implemented solely using local files?

Comment: Yes, you can create external js and upload it to master page gallery or in site content. Do care while mentioning url in JSLink property. As it contain ~sitecollection or ~site, so take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try with below jquery if it helps you for checking the values and updating the row colors:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Open')");
    $Text.parent().css("background-color", "#FF9900");
});
```